# Scale & Translate animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I require an animation for an image in my application.
The image should start coming from the top left corner till the middle of screen. The image size will be smaller at the initial stage. While coming to the middle of the screen, its size should increase(i.e. scaling should take place). Image should not go back to its original position. It should be placed at the middle of the screen itself after the animation.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Please find the answer here.
Create an xml inside /res/anim folder and put the below code into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
   <scale android:fromXScale="0.0" android:fromYScale="0.0"
          android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0" 
          android:duration="700" android:fillBefore="false" />
   <translate android:fromXDelta="-200" android:fromYDelta="-200"
          android:duration="700" />
</set>
```

Place the below code inside the java file:

```
Animation logoMoveAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.logoanimation); 
logoIV.startAnimation(logoMoveAnimation);
```

logoanimation is the name of my animation xml file.

Thanks for all those who tried out for my question.

Comment: hi Mathew, i tried similar kind of animation but the image goes back to the original position and scale after the animation ends.how to prevent  the image from going back to the original position and scale after the animation ends?

Comment: @Pravy :- try adding this to the XML >>> android:repeatCount="0"

Comment: @Pravy you could also try adding the following xml line: android:fillAfter="true"

Comment: is there any way to pause this animation?

Comment: is `logoIV` the name of the view to animate? it's not working for me.

Comment: How do i get it to scale from right instead of from left?

Comment: To avoid the image returning to its original size, I had to add an animation listener and manually adjust its property values onAnimationEnd. `animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener {...})`

It may have to do with the issue with views listed in this link related to the button. [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#how]

Comment: @ThomasTeilmann, use pivotX and pivotY as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#scale-element (and examples).

Comment: Thanks, that works. A problem is solved by placing `scale` tag before `translate`.