# How to create Animation start from center of an image

Tags: android, animation

I have a custom dialog class which is used to popup an image when touch on it.The dialog is shown at the center of the screen.I am setting pop up and push down animation for this dialog.

popup_show.xml

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```

popup_hide.xml

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

These animations work perfectly.By using these animations the dialog is pop up center of the screen.

But i want to make this dialog popup from center of the image and shown at the center of the screen. Otherwise how to start a dialog from center of the image and shown at center of the screen ?
How it is possible?

Thanks,

Comment: so, the image is not in the center of the screen, but dialogs final position is?

Comment: Image is at top of the screen.dialogs final position is at center of the screen

Comment: Have You tried to just use animation <set> and add <translate> animation from center of the image?

Comment: How can i use this.Show me a sample

Comment: How do you add tell the popup window to get the popup_hide or the popup_show xmls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this mi8 help:

```
<scale                
android:toXScale="1.0"              
android:fromXScale="0.0"            

android:toYScale="1.0"
android:fromYScale="0.0"

android:pivotX="0%"
android:pivotY="0%"

android:startOffset="100"
android:duration="1000">
</scale>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's possible using either [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152041/scale-translate-animation) or [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422421/android-image-view-scale-animation).

The only thing You need is to do calculation before animation start - center of the image (call smth like `View.getLocationOnScreen()` or `View.getLocationInWindow()`).

Answer (score 0):

Use this style

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="250"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />
```